# Change cursor position in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to change the position of the cursor over a particular label. I use:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Cursor.Position = Label17.Location

End Sub
```

but it doesn't change where I want it. I tried:

```
   Label16.Location = Label17.Location
```

And this move the label16 properly.

So How do we move the cursor to the location of label17 or any label/object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Label.Location (and any other Control.Location) refers to location *relative to the upper-left corner of its container*. This mean that you must call the PointToScreen method of the parent container. In a simple application that just have a Form without any other container, it will be:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Cursor.Position = Me.PointToScreen(Label17.Location)

End Sub
```

A more elegant one:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Cursor.Position = Label17.Parent.PointToScreen(Label17.Location)

End Sub
```